# Is there any mention of Lord Krishna in the Rāmāyaṇa?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, krishna, ramayana

In the [Canto CXIX.: Glory To Vishnu](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry490.htm#fr_1042)
of the *Yuddha Kāṇḍa* of the *Valmikí Rāmāyaṇa*, after *Rāvaṇa* has been defeated, all deities appear in the sky and eulogize *Shri Rāma*, as Lord *Vishnu* himself and **the word *Krishna* is made reference to**.

> Thou all-pervading *Vishnu* Lord Who wears the ever-conquering sword;
> Thou art the Guide who leads aright, **Thou *Krishna* of unequalled might.**
> Thy hand, O Lord, the hills and plains, And earth with all her life
> sustains; Thou wilt appear in serpent form When sinks the earth in
> fire and storm. Queen *Sítá* of the lovely brows Is *Lakshmí* thy
> celestial spouse

The [Sanskrit version](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rys/rys6105.htm)

> अक्षरं ब्रह्मसत्यं च मध्ये चान्ते च राघव।
>  लॊकानां तवं परॊ धर्मॊ विष्वक्सेनश चतुर्भुजः ॥13 
> शार्ङ्गधन्वा हृषीकेशः पुरुषः पुरुषॊत्तमः।
>              अजितः खड्गधृग विष्णुः **कृष्णश चैव** बृहद्बलः॥14॥
>
> akṣaraṃ brahmasatyaṃ ca madhye cānte ca  rāghava । 
> lokānāṃ tvaṃ paro dharmo viṣvaksenaś  caturbhujaḥ ॥13॥
> śārṅgadhanvā hṛṣīkeśaḥ puruṣaḥ
> puruṣottamaḥ ।
> ajitaḥ khaḍgadhṛg viṣṇuḥ **kṛṣṇaś caiva** bṛhadbalaḥ ॥14॥

---

So, **my question is**, here *Krishna* is to be taken as the adjective which means -  "The most attractive one / the one who's  all attractive / the one who's of dark complexion". Or it is to be taken in the proper noun form, i.e., the incarnation of the Lord - *"Shri Krishna"*?
Also, considering time is cyclic, it doesn't matter whatever form the Lord incarnates, the *trikāladarśin* seers, must be knowing everything, I guess? In that way, the proper noun interpretation seems more logical to me. I'd appreciate some supportive commentaries by competent *sanksrit acharyas or gurus* on this word meaning interpretation dilemma posed in here.

Comment: Once again an interesting question, and I think this one has a definite answer.

Comment: Krishna means black / blue, the colour of Bhagwan Vishnu. Also since gods and the incarnations repeat Vishnu can be called by names of Krishna also. For example in Balakanda they say for Sita : केशवाङ्कच्युता - separated from Vishnu’s lap. Keshava is used for both Krishna and Vishnu. So you can think of it from these two perspectives.

Comment: @Archit, yeah, I forgot that to mention. Thanks!

Comment: @Surya, Thanks. yeah, This one is definitely not opinion based, I guess! :P

Comment: Is your question specific to Krsna, or as you mentioned in the last line, other avataras too can be listed?

Comment: @Surya, Emphasis in more on *Krishna*. But, I'd want a full answer covering whatever all is asked in the question. :P

Comment: @Could you maybe split that as a separate question, like "Which avataras of Vishnu are mentioned in the Ramayana?" That way this question can remained focused on the Krsna line.

Comment: @Surya, perhaps, sounds legit. I'll do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *So, my question is, here Krishna is to be taken as the adjective which means - "The most attractive one / the one who's all attractive / the one who's of dark complexion".*
>
> *Or it is to be taken in the proper noun form, i.e., the incarnation of the Lord - "Shri Krishna"?*

It appears most translators of Rāmāyaṇa consider *kṛṣṇa* to be a proper noun i.e., Kṛṣṇa, the avatāra of Viṣṇu, given the context, whereas the traditional commentators treat it as an adjective mainly to resolve the contradiction that how could the author of Rāmāyaṇa or the assembled devas have known about a future incarnation of Viṣṇu.

Here's how Robert P. Goldman et al., [translate](https://books.google.com/books?id=vDibDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) those verses:

> #### Sarga 105
>
> 1–3. Then King Kubera Vaiśravaṇa; Yama, dragger of his foes; great Indra of the thousand eyes; Varuṇa, scorcher of his foes; the great god, majestic Śiva, with his half-six eyes and the bull on his banner; and Brahmā, foremost of those who know the vedas, the creator of the entire universe—all these assembled in their flying chariots as radiant as the sun, and, coming to the city of Laṅkā, they approached Rāghava.
>
> 4. Then, raising their broad arms covered with bracelets, the foremost of the thirty gods addressed Rāghava, who stood before them, his hands cupped in reverence.
> 5. "How can you, the creator of the entire universe, the most ancient one, and foremost among those possessing supreme knowledge, stand by and watch as Sītā falls into the fire, eater of oblations? How can you not realize that you are the foremost among the hosts of the gods?"
>
> ...
>
> 13. "You are the imperishable Brahman, existent in the beginning, the middle, and the end. You are the highest governing principal of all the worlds, the four-armed Viṣvaksena."
> 14. "You are the wielder of the horn bow, you are Hṛṣikeśa, the primal person, the Supreme Spirit. You are Viṣṇu, the invincible wielder of the sword, and **you are Kṛṣṇa of immense strength.**"
> 15. "You are the leader of the hosts. You are the leader of all beings. You are intelligence, strength, forbearance, and self-control. You are the origin and the dissolution. You are Upendra, Indra's younger brother, and Madhusūdana, slayer of the asura Madhu."
>
> ...
>
> 23. "Your body is this world; your steadfastness, the earth. Agni is your wrath; Soma, your gentleness, O bearer of the Śrīvatsa mark."
> 24. "In ancient times, you spanned the three worlds with as many strides. After confining the great asura Bali, you made great Indra king."
> 25. "Sītā is Lakṣmī; you are the god Viṣṇu. **You are Kṛṣṇa.** You are Prajāpati, the lord of creatures. It was in order to slay Rāvaṇa that you entered a human body here."
> 26. "Thus have you accomplished our purpose, foremost of upholders of righteousness. Rāvaṇa has been slain. Now, Rāma, in your delight, please return to heaven."
>
> ...
>
> #### NOTES:
>
> 14. ... "and you are Kṛṣṇa of immense strength" *kṛṣṇaś caiva bṛhadbalaḥ*: Roussel (1903, vol. 3, p. 389) and Pagani (1999, p. 1187) understand *bṛhadbalaḥ* as a separate proper name. Dutt (1893, p. 1511) and Shastri (1959, vol. 3, p. 339) render it separately as an adjective. Raghunathan (1982, vol. 3, p. 340) and Gita Press (1969, vol. 3, p. 1855) appear to translate as we do. Most commentators understand the term *bṛhadbalaḥ*, "of immense strength," to refer to the Lord's great power to sustain or uphold (*dharaṇasāmarthyam*—so Cg). Ct and Ck take it to mean that he has the ability to hold up the entire universe as if it were a ball to play with (*aśeṣabrahmaṇdasya līlākandukavaddhāraṇakṣamaḥ*—so Ct). Cm, however, takes the epithet to be to the *Rāmāvatāra*, understanding *bala* in its sense of "army," and glossing, "he who has great armies of monkeys (*bṛhanti vānarabalāni yasyeti tathā*)." On the name Kṛṣṇa, see note to verse 25 below.
>
> ...
>
> 25. "You are Kṛṣṇa" *kṛṣṇah*: Literally, "Kṛṣṇa." **The commentators generally agree that this term should be taken in its adjectival sense of "black, blue-black, or of a dark color (*kṛṣṇavarṇaḥ*)." This is probably because they wish to avoid the apparent anachronism of mentioning an *avatāra* who will not appear until the next cosmic age.** Nonetheless, in the context of this thoroughgoing Vaiṣṇava *stotra*, like all translators consulted, with the exception of Raghunathan, **we believe that the reference is probably to the name of the other major *avatāra* of Viṣṇu.** Raghunathan (1982, vol. 3, p. 341), reading the adjective with *devaḥ*, "the god," renders, "the Lord that has assumed a dark form." See note to verse 14 above.
>
> "You are Prajāpati, the lord of creatures." *prajāpatiḥ*: Literally, "Prajāpati." The epithet is most frequently used of the speaker, Brahmā himself. See note to verse 6 above.

Comment: your answer make my head spin :-)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. So now, we have two different interpretations. One (the Indian interpretations) says it's interpreted as complexion, other (non indian maybe) says, it's proper noun.

Comment: It's interesting to note that if we are considering proper nouns, Ajita would be a proper noun too, referring to the Lord's incarnation during Samudra Mathana to hold Mandara mountain from the top.

Comment: 'other (non-Indian maybe) says, it's proper noun' - even Indian translators translate it as Kṛṣṇa. [Here's M. N. Dutt's translation](https://archive.org/details/Valmiki_Ramayana_English_Prose_Translation_7_volumes_by_Manmatha_Nath_Dutt_1891_to_1894/Valmiki%20Ramayana%20-%20MN%20Dutt%20-%20Volume%206%20-%20Yuddha%20Kanda%201893/page/n417/mode/2up): "thou art Vishnu holding dagger, Krishna and of incomparable strength" @Vivikta

Comment: Quite interesting, @Surya, if interpreted proper noun way then it adds up for another addition as an answer to my [THIS question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45419/which-incarnations-of-lord-vishnu-are-mentioned-in-the-ra%cc%84ma%cc%84yan%cc%a3a)

Comment: @Vivikta it sure does, but one is not sure whether the reference is to Ajita or to the Unconquerable One.

Comment: That's why I love sanskrit, @Surya. I have always thought, all kinds of interpretations can generally considered equally valid for any sanskrit verse. That's its beauty. And thus, it serves everyone as per their own leanings  and *samskaras*. In many ways, kind of a Universal language of the Divine, if you'll.  :))

Answer (score 6):

There is mention of word Krishna in Ramayana several time but that should be taken as adjective which means "the most attractive one / the one who's all attractive / the one who's of dark complexion" etc.

To clarify, see this shloka from [119 Sarga of Yudhaa Kanada](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse28):

> सीता लक्ष्मीर्भवान् विष्णुर्देवः **कृष्णः** प्रजापतिः || ६-११७-२८
>
> वधार्थं रावणस्येह प्रविष्टो मानुषीं तनुम् |

> "Seetha is no other than Goddess Lakshmi (the divine consort of Lord Vishnu), while you are Lord Vishnu. **You are having a shining dark-blue hue**. You are the Lord of created beings. For the destruction of Ravana, you entered a human body here, on this earth."

Comment: I remember reading long ago somewhere it translated it as a Noun. Maybe it was error then. Thanks for the answer though!