# Which incarnations of Lord Vishnu are mentioned in the Rāmāyaṇa?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, itihasa

Like the *Mahābhārata* has several explicit references to various incarnations of Lord *Vishnu*, including that of *Shri Rāma*, What about the *Rāmāyaṇa*?

Which all incarnations of the Lord, have been mentioned either explicitly or implicitly in the *Rāmāyaṇa*?

---

One may also derive their answers from the other popular versions of the *Rāmāyaṇas* - *Adbhuta*, *Ānanda*, *Adhyātma*, et al.

Answer (score 5):

From Dashaavtaras:

- [Varaha](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddha_117_frame.htm)
- [Vamana (Upendra)](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddha_117_frame.htm)
- [Parashu Rama](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga75/bala_75_frame.htm)
- [Rama](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga75/bala_75_frame.htm)
- [Narasimha](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-24)
- [Kurma (the tortoise)](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga45/bala_45_frame.htm)

From others:

- [Narada](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga1/bala_1_frame.htm)
- [Rishi Narayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-63)
- [Mandhata](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga70/bala_70_frame.htm)
- [Sanatkumara](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-43)
- [Dhanvantari, Mohini and other avtaras of Samudra manthana](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga45/bala_45_frame.htm)

*Note:* There might be few others as well.

---

Related

[What are the Avatarams of Vishnu described in the Yuddha Kanda of the Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/62/what-are-the-avatarams-of-vishnu-described-in-the-yuddha-kanda-of-the-ramayana?rq=1)

[Mahavishnu's Avataaras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23062/mahavishnus-avataaras)

[What form of Vishnu held Mandara at the top during the Churning of the Ocean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19039/what-form-of-vishnu-held-mandara-at-the-top-during-the-churning-of-the-ocean)

Comment: Interesting that you also added Mandhata!

Comment: If possible add line or two describing each one of these ,  this way it will not be a link only answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar These links are not needed..only name needed here, right? so even if these links go dead, answer will still be valid..bcz from the link we r taking name only :)

Comment: @Surya Yes, Mandhata is also an incarnation https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23062/mahavishnus-avataaras/23092#23092

Comment: Yeah that is an interesting fact. Also what @SwiftPushkar means is you can give the quotations of the verses rather than just giving link so even if the link goes wrong, we can read the verses' translation here.

Comment: @YDS , you can add Kurma avatara from [Balakanda Sarga 45](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga45/bala_45_frame.htm), the avatara of Matsya in [Yuddha Kanda 117.13](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddha_117_frame.htm). If you like, you can add the North Western Recension also mentions: Hayagriva, Narayana Rishi and Nara. And Hari. - नारायणाय ऋषये नराय हरये नमः। त्वम् अश्ववदनो भूत्वा पातालतलमास्थितः॥ यु॰ ९८।४२

Comment: @Archit Done, couldn't find Matsya/fish though in the link which shloka mentions it? And is there any link for the last shloka?

Comment: @YDS no link for the last shloka it’s not commonly available. Accha for Matsya avatar sorry it’s the verse Yuddha Kanda 117.14 not 117.13. Idk why the verse didn’t link properly instead while chapter did. : **एकशृङ्गो** वराहस्त्वं भूतभव्यसपत्नजित्. Ekashringa = Matsya. Not one tusked Varaha

Comment: Hm, looks possible but let's hold on that then..will see few other translations...

Comment: One very important thing while reading Valmiki for references is to look at the similes he uses - he links many characters through similes.

Comment: There is this extremely beautiful reference to Narasimha Avatara in [Yuddha Kanda 18.23](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga18/yuddha_18_frame.htm)

Comment: @Archit What is the situation where Hayagriva and Nara-Narayana appear? The Southern Recension Sarga 98 is Angada vs Mahaparshva

Comment: @Surya it comes when praising Rama as Sakshat Vishnu corresponding to 117 of SR

Comment: @Archit Checked gitapress translation too..no mention of Matsya..if u hv any translation or commentary, u can directly edit the answer...

Comment: It'll be better if you can directly give those verses too below each name of the avatar you mention. Just hyper linking makes it too broad to search the linked page. Maybe, then I can accept the answer.